# How to make a GWT-like CaptionPanel manually

Tags: html, css, jsf, gwt

I am developping a JSF webapp, and I would like to make the same thing as GWT's CaptionPanel (title on the top border, see [here](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/user-interface/caption-panel)). I did not find a JSF equivalent to it. How can I get the same result with pure HTML/CSS?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [HTML fieldset tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp).

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Title</legend>
</fieldset>
```